# Calling java method contain string as argument and string as return type from c++ in ndk in android

Tags: android-ndk

I have one following methods in java:

```
public native String jniStringMethod();

public String stringMethod(String s) {
  Log.d("Testing", "String:" + s);
  return s;
}
```

I am trying to call "stringMethod" method in `jniStringMethod()` in cpp file in the following way:

```
jstring Java_ashok_learning_ndk_SampleNDKActivity_jniStringMethod(JNIEnv *env,
  jobject obj) {
   jstring jstr = env->NewStringUTF("This comes from jni string .");

  //jclass clazz = env->GetObjectClass(obj);
   jclass clazz = env->FindClass("ashok/learning/ndk/SampleNDKActivity");
  if (0 == clazz) {
    LOG("clazz class not found!");
  }

  jmethodID messageMe = env->GetMethodID(clazz, "stringMethod", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;");

  if (0 == messageMe) {
    LOG("messageMe method not found!");
  }
  jobject result = env->CallObjectMethod(obj, messageMe, jstr);
  LOG("result: %d", result);

  const char* str = env->GetStringUTFChars((jstring)result, NULL); // should be released but what a heck, it's a tutorial :)
  printf("%s\n", str);

  return env->NewStringUTF(str);
}
```

But it is not getting called..and i am getting log as "messageMe method not found!",means method is not matching with signature...any one can suggest about my mistakes?

Comment: `jobject result = env->CallObjectMethod(obj, messageMe, jstr);
  LOG("result: %d", result);

  const char* str = env->GetStringUTFChars((jstring)result, NULL); // should be released but what a heck, it's a tutorial :)
  printf("%s\n", str);` these lines help me

Answer (score 0):

Your signture is OK. Are you sure your code is not executed properly even though `messageMe` is NULL? It has happend to me that my code was running fine despite `jmethodID` being NULL.